# Firebase hosting deployment fails with "Server Error. socket hang up"

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

> **Console Output**

```
$ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to '***'...

i  deploying database, storage, firestore, functions, hosting
i  database: checking rules syntax...
✔  database: rules syntax for database stulz-monitor is valid
i  storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
✔  storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
✔  firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  storage: uploading rules storage.rules...
i  firestore: uploading rules firestore.rules...
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (61.81 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...

Error: Server Error. socket hang up
```

> firebase-debug.log

```
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.359Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.362Z] Command:       /Users/Sanket/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/node /Users/Sanket/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/firebase deploy
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.362Z] CLI Version:   3.15.2
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.362Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.362Z] Node Version:  v7.10.0
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.363Z] Time:          Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:06 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.363Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.376Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.376Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.378Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"]
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.378Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token { refresh_token: '**********',
  client_id: '***-***.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret: '***',
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  scope: 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase openid' } 
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:06 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.772Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:06.786Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:06 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:09.144Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:09.145Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/stulz-monitor/tokens  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:09 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:10.275Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'stulz-monitor'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying database, storage, firestore, functions, hosting
[info] i  database: checking rules syntax...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:13.405Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://stulz-monitor.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json?dryRun=true {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "false"
  }
}

 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:13 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:14.696Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  database: rules syntax for database stulz-monitor is valid
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:14.698Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/stulz-monitor  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:14 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:16.644Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] i  storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:16.651Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor:test { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:16 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:18.967Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
[info] i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:18.974Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor:test { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:18 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:20.087Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:20.089Z] > [functions] package.json contents: {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
[info] i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
[info] i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:20.091Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/projectSettings/stulz-monitor?view=CONSUMER_VIEW  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:20 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:20.091Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/projectSettings/stulz-monitor?view=CONSUMER_VIEW  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:20 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:22.106Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:22.403Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:22.405Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/stulz-monitor  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:22 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:22.406Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://apikeys.googleapis.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor/apiKeys  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:22 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:24.197Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:24.610Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] i  storage: uploading rules storage.rules...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:24.615Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor/rulesets { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:24 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:25.990Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:25.990Z] [rules] created ruleset projects/stulz-monitor/rulesets/98ac1f07-a129-4ff1-ac20-1638fb3c2e30
[info] i  firestore: uploading rules firestore.rules...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:25.994Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor/rulesets { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:25 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:25.995Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/stulz-monitor/databases/(default)/indexes  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:25 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:27.258Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:27.259Z] [rules] created ruleset projects/stulz-monitor/rulesets/591c5d82-24bd-4146-8b75-4f672c24671a
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:28.077Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:40.095Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/stulz-monitor/configs  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:40 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:40.685Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] i  functions: packaged functions (61.81 KB) for uploading
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:48.198Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/staging.stulz-monitor.appspot.com  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:48 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:48.865Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:48.866Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/staging.stulz-monitor.appspot.com/o?uploadType=media&name=firebase-functions-source ReadStream {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 65536,
     buffer: BufferList { head: [Object], tail: [Object], length: 1 },
     length: 63292,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: true,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: { end: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  path: '/var/folders/n3/h9nbc_ys2732s35_9jlgh98c0000gn/T/firebase-functions-6515Ngn1HNgoFfUM.zip',
  fd: 19,
  flags: 'r',
  mode: 438,
  start: undefined,
  end: undefined,
  autoClose: true,
  pos: undefined,
  bytesRead: 63292 } 
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:48 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:50.768Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
[info] i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:36:50.944Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/hosting/stulz-monitor/uploads/-KzZ98-Ef8hX6Lqfgw2J?fileCount=16&message=  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:06:50 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:37:52.379Z] Error: socket hang up
    at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1120:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. socket hang up
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:33.433Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:33.436Z] Command:       /Users/Sanket/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/node /Users/Sanket/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/firebase deploy --only hosting
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:33.437Z] CLI Version:   3.15.2
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:33.437Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:33.437Z] Node Version:  v7.10.0
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:33.437Z] Time:          Wed Nov 22 2017 20:08:33 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:33.437Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:33.452Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:33.452Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:33.455Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:08:33 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:34.805Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:34.807Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/stulz-monitor/tokens  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:08:34 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:36.037Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'stulz-monitor'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying hosting
[info] i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:38:38.871Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/hosting/stulz-monitor/uploads/-KzZ9djhjEHEc1iN3KTI?fileCount=16&message=  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:08:38 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:44.756Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:44.759Z] Command:       /Users/Sanket/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/node /Users/Sanket/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/firebase deploy
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:44.759Z] CLI Version:   3.15.2
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:44.759Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:44.759Z] Node Version:  v7.10.0
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:44.760Z] Time:          Wed Nov 22 2017 20:11:44 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:44.760Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:44.775Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:44.775Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:44.778Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:11:44 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:47.277Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:47.278Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/stulz-monitor/tokens  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:11:47 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:49.540Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'stulz-monitor'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying database, storage, firestore, functions, hosting
[info] i  database: checking rules syntax...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:52.281Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://stulz-monitor.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json?dryRun=true {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "false"
  }
}

 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:11:52 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:53.550Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  database: rules syntax for database stulz-monitor is valid
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:53.552Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/stulz-monitor  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:11:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:55.852Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] i  storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:55.859Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor:test { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:11:55 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:57.208Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
[info] i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:57.216Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor:test { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:11:57 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:58.592Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:58.598Z] > [functions] package.json contents: {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
[info] i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
[info] i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:58.599Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/projectSettings/stulz-monitor?view=CONSUMER_VIEW  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:11:58 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:41:58.600Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/projectSettings/stulz-monitor?view=CONSUMER_VIEW  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:11:58 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:00.952Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:01.185Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:01.186Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/stulz-monitor  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:12:01 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:01.186Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://apikeys.googleapis.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor/apiKeys  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:12:01 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:02.850Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:02.902Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] i  storage: uploading rules storage.rules...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:02.908Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor/rulesets { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:12:02 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:07.651Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:07.652Z] [rules] created ruleset projects/stulz-monitor/rulesets/ab4b440f-7ced-48f1-ac72-fd53aaf85597
[info] i  firestore: uploading rules firestore.rules...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:07.655Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/stulz-monitor/rulesets { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:12:07 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:07.657Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/stulz-monitor/databases/(default)/indexes  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:12:07 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:09.570Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:13.542Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:13.543Z] [rules] created ruleset projects/stulz-monitor/rulesets/bfab570a-f997-41b8-a6d3-1c77a41572c5
[info] i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:25.884Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/stulz-monitor/configs  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:12:25 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:31.838Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] i  functions: packaged functions (61.81 KB) for uploading
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:39.537Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/staging.stulz-monitor.appspot.com  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:12:39 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:40.019Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:40.020Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/staging.stulz-monitor.appspot.com/o?uploadType=media&name=firebase-functions-source ReadStream {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 65536,
     buffer: BufferList { head: [Object], tail: [Object], length: 1 },
     length: 63292,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: true,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: { end: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  path: '/var/folders/n3/h9nbc_ys2732s35_9jlgh98c0000gn/T/firebase-functions-6597f3AGZ4D601g7.zip',
  fd: 19,
  flags: 'r',
  mode: 438,
  start: undefined,
  end: undefined,
  autoClose: true,
  pos: undefined,
  bytesRead: 63292 } 
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:12:40 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:47.020Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
[info] i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:42:47.219Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/hosting/stulz-monitor/uploads/-KzZAQa7e_nVP17jXgzQ?fileCount=16&message=  
 Wed Nov 22 2017 20:12:47 GMT+0530 (IST)
[debug] [2017-11-22T14:44:39.346Z] Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:302:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:394:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. socket hang up
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late to answer this, but anyway i'll do it.
I too faced with this problem many times. Then I found that it is caused by unstable internet connection. Try with other networks and you may be able to deploy, or try restarting your internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

I had issues with this when deploying while using a VPN like tunnelbear. Try disabling that and see if it helps.

I have also tried deleted my cloud functions from google cloud console before trying to deploy again, which has helped in other similarly weird circumstances. 
https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list?project=

Answer (score 2):

This is late but may be helpful for someone. For me it was just due to bad internet connection. It failed like 3-4 times literally (it was the same time window in which my internet got limited that i was getting "socket hung up message"). So make sure internet is working fine. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved itself automatically after a while.
It seems like it was a problem from Google's end.

Comment: I am having this issue since 4 days

Comment: @Md.AbdulHalimRafi maybe try to update your local DNS server to 8.8.8.8